# What is the impact of spelling mistakes for users?

Tags: grammar, perception, professionalism, first-impression

My team developed a site that has a lot of spelling and grammatical mistakes.
Does this leave a bad impression for first time visiting users?

Comment: I already have a bad impression of @abdul wakeel just from reading the question. If someone can't be bothered to take the time to use correct spelling and grammar, it's not worth my time to help them/use their product/deal with all the other issues that are going to be found because they weren't spending time on the product.

Comment: @zzzBov , i accept, but i write this post while chatting with the team members. so that's why there is grammatical mistakes.

Comment: provide suggestion how to overcome these types of mistakes?

Comment: @zzzzBov - Not everyone in the world speaks English as their first language, have some consideration.

Comment: Good, but if there is hidden (unexpected) mistakes, like tooltips.  you know software have bugs.

Comment: @Matt, as a polyglot I understand that there are more people who speak english as a second language than there are who speak it as their first. That is not an excuse. If I needed to write something in another language, I would have someone fluent in the language review what I've written so as to *fix* my errors. I actually upvoted this question, as it's legitimate.

Comment: so from your comments i derived that we should hire someone fluent in the English language, but we can not effort it.

Comment: @abdul. I think you meant *cannot afford it*.

Comment: @trig yes sure afford.

Comment: @abdul wakeel: it sounds like English is not your native language, in which case you may be better getting a freelance copywriter who is a native speaker. Comments below suggest automated spelling and grammar checks, but that will only get you so far--for instance, I'm not sure they'll be helpful for that afford/effort mistake above. I see you say you can't afford it, but can you afford to lose the people you're driving away? You may be able to hire a good copywriter for a fixed number of hours to start with your most important pages, then get more as you can pay for it.

Comment: i can not afford content writer.

Comment: @Abdul, then read more books to improve your grammar. Additionally, not capitalizing "i" makes you look childish.

Comment: Don't you know any students that study english? They won't translate for free but perhaps that would be a cheaper alternative.

Comment: @Abdul. Ignore the negativity in these comments. You know there is an issue and you are attempting to fix it - there will always be ignorant people who criticize. The answers you have received are more important and constructive - concentrate on them. Best,

Comment: @antony - it is also ironic that no one has fixed *your* spelling mistakes. It is "it's" and "no one", not "its" and "noone".

Comment: @gef05 - the negativity in these comments is because he is not listening to the advice given. The only way to fix spelling and grammatical errors is to hire someone capable of doing so. He has said he will not do that, so there is nothing else to be done.

Comment: i am now trying http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I strongly advise against leaving spelling/grammar mistakes on your site or any other product you may want to publish. Here's why: lots of spelling/grammar mistakes makes your product seem suspicious. It is a prejudice, but a justified one; people receive a lot of spam, scam, phishing, and other similar mails. The only reliable way to tell who is trustworthy or not (aside from looking at the sender address), is paying attention to mistakes.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**broken?**

"If not even the spelling is correct, how can I trust this works correctly?" This is especially troublesome for web sites that want to hold private data. I might not even want to give you my e-mail.

**dead?**

When obvious errors remain online for a long time, this suggests that

- you don't care to fix them (lack of respect)
- you are technically unable to do so (I can not rely on the site being available tomorrow)

**cheap!** (in a bad way)

I.e. you couldn't even find someone to proof-read the web site, your budget is so tight that you can't afford to be friendly.

The shared theme is **loss of trust**.

I understand that especially the last point is not very fair towards non-native speakers, especially with completely different language roots and without easy access to native speakers of the foreign language. However, this is the cost to do business abroad

Comment: +1 for  I might not even want to give you my e-mail

Comment: I would add **lazy**: didn't bother to run content through spell check. Most browsers & text editors have some form of spell check that will catch at least some errors (even if grammar & usage errors still slip through).

Comment: Whenever I arrive on a site with numerous spelling and grammatical errors, I assume it is something fradulent or otherwise untrustworthy.  It reminds me of all the Viagra emails I get.

Comment: once i write content, or do some work, i forgot to check it back. all time i have confidence that i did it right.

Comment: Good examples, now we are almost ready without spelling mistake

Answer (score 23):

**Yes this will leave a bad impression.**

And remember, first impressions are very important. I would get this corrected as soon as possible. Not only will it make the site/company look unprofessional, but it will be difficult to understand. No offense intended, but I actually had to read this question a couple times to fully understand what you were saying (English is probably your second language). That is fine in an informal setting like this, but on a company site, you want it to be as perfect as possible.

Comment: +1 for reading(but I actually had to read this question a couple times to fully understand what you were saying (English is probably your second language)

Comment: but i have seen spelling mistake in reputed world class websites.

Comment: My impression was that this question *intentionally* uses bad spelling and grammar.  It is sort of a parody of the sites it asks about.

Comment: @GEdger - Clever observation, but I don't think that's true in this case.

Comment: @abdul wakeel: absolutely, and although they sometimes make me cringe, there's a difference when there's one spelling/grammar mistake per thousand words and when there's one spelling/grammar mistake per ten words.

Comment: but any way you accept there is spelling mistake in high profile sites, either its one or hundred.

Comment: @abdul I would buy a used car with a few small scratches.  I would not buy a used car with broken windows, flat tires, or a "W'04" bumper sticker.

Comment: Now that the question is edited, it doesn't seem to be intentionally bad.

Comment: if some one english speaker write arabia then he will make same mistake which arabain have done to write english.

Answer (score 22):

Spelling mistakes can have quite a large impact on your site's visitors. A quote from the [Stanford Guidelines for Web Credibility](http://credibility.stanford.edu/guidelines/index.html)

> Typographical errors and broken links hurt a site's credibility more than most people imagine. It's also important to keep your site up and running.

Typos make your site look amateurish, just like broken links or unavailable content can do. From the user's point of view this affects your organisation's trustworthiness and perceived expertise in a negative way.

Comment: most of the time Arabic or non English speaker have grammatical mistake.

Comment: +1. Whenever I get mail, the trustworthy ones have little to no spelling/grammar mistakes, regardless of which language they were written in. The ones that have lots of mistakes are usually spam, scam, phishing attempts, etc. Because of that, sites with lots of mistakes seem extremely suspicious to me. One exception is when the mistakes come from users of the site.

Answer (score 10):

Abdul, there is one other thing to be aware of.

There are many established websites with high visitor counts that contain spelling and grammatical errors - but a spelling mistake on those sites is different from a spelling mistake on other sites (such as yours).

When your site is established and well-respected (like BBC News) typos are bad, but users will overlook them because of everything else the site offers - in this example, established reporting that can be trusted.

When your site is trying to establish itself, and people do not know if they can trust you, every little mistake gets a spotlight shone on it - and spelling errors are just that sort of mistake.

Comment: +1 for, but a spelling mistake on those sites is different from a spelling mistake on other sites

Comment: please provide the suggestion how to overcome these type of mistake?

Comment: There are online tools available: see http://www.spellcheck.net/. You could also use - and you'll hate this - a word processing application like MS Word or Open Office Writer. Copy and paste your text, select English as the language, and do a spell check. Very tedious. Hopefully someone will see this and know of an automated way of handling this.

Comment: that's good, let me forward your message to member's.

Comment: I'd also recommend doing a grammar check, although it's more painful. You'll probably want to do a few of them with a native speaker nearby to let you know which grammar "mistakes" can regularly be ignored (e.g., "passive voice").

Comment: but spell checker only deal with spell. what to do with Grammatical mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Spell Check is never something to rely upon completely. I have a client who mentioned the vast array of products in their "whorehouses". It was spelled correctly, but not exactly accurate.

Comment: I think the most important is understanding.. if some one understand , then spell does not matter. either its correct or not. (not in public GUI) the rule is generally for chatting or commenting

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way. It takes years of highly specialized training to become a qualified developer, but even school students are *required* to be able (and many are actually able) to write correctly. So writing correctly is cheaper than developing complex technical stuff like a web site. If even one of the cheapest parts can't be done right how can users not have a bad impression?

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out:   Error messages are a common place for both spelling mistakes and difficult to understand text.

If you get a third party to check your site they often won't know how to trigger them, so they won't find them all.